# Turning textual answers into dichotomous variables

Tags: sql, data-analysis, spss

I've done research using the google forms and now I need to prepare that data for the further analysis. The point is I don't really know how to go about that.
I have variables (questionnaire questions), each of this question have four answers. In my data those answers are just strings, so let's say:

```
Variable 1 (Here is a question)
Value = Answer (C. The answer)
```

Now I need to split every one of those variable into four different ones and the representation of that data should look like that:

```
Variable 1_1 where Value = 0
Variable 1_2 where Value = 0
Variable 1_3 where Value = 1 -> because as you seen above answer C was chosen.
Variable 1_4 where Value = 0
```

So here is the recoding part. It's not string anymore but 0 or 1.

Well I hope that this make sense. And thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this one variable at a time, you can use:

```
IF (variable1="a") variable1_1=1 .
IF (variable1="b") variable1_2=1 .
IF (variable1="c") variable1_3=1 .
IF (variable1="d") variable1_4=1 .
RECODE variable1_1 TO variable1_4 (SYSMIS=0) .
EXE .
```

If all of your variables have the same response structure and you want to loop through all of them at once, you can use `VECTOR` to do that.

```
VECTOR variable = variable1 TO variable100 /* existing variables */ .
VECTOR response1_var = response1_var (100,F1) /* create new vars, response1_var1 TO response1_var100 */ .
VECTOR response2_var = response2_var (100,F1) /* create new vars, response2_var1 TO response2_var100 */ .
VECTOR response3_var = response3_var (100,F1) .
VECTOR response4_var = response4_var (100,F1) .
LOOP #i = 1 TO 100 .
IF (variable(#i)="a") response1_var(#i)=1 .
IF (variable(#i)="b") response2_var(#i)=1 .
IF (variable(#i)="c") response3_var(#i)=1 .
IF (variable(#i)="d") response4_var(#i)=1 .
END LOOP .
RECODE response1_var1 TO response4_var100 (SYSMIS=0) .
EXE .
```

Keep in mind that looping through this way would order your new variables by "response series" as oppose to questionnaire order. If you wanted to either re-order or rename your new variables that could be done separately.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, so here is one.
first to make some fake data to demonstrate on:

```
data list free/var1 to var4 (4a1).
begin data 
"a" "b" "a" "c" "c" "b" "a" "c"  "d" "d" "a" "b"
end data.
```

Now a separate `recode` command for each possible answer - each command taking care of all the relevant variables which have those possible answers:

```
recode var1 to var4  ("a"=1)(else=0)  into varA1 to varA4.
recode var1 to var4  ("b"=1)(else=0)  into varB1 to varB4.
recode var1 to var4  ("c"=1)(else=0)  into varC1 to varC4.
recode var1 to var4  ("d"=1)(else=0)  into varD1 to varD4.
```